# Netbeans: how to create an executable .jar file with all libraries and resource files included?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, executable-jar

I tried `clean and build` and found a .jar file in the `dist` directory. However, the libraries and resource files the program needs to run properly are absent in the .jar file. One workaround is put all libraries and resource files somewhere in the same directory or sub-directory of the .jar file. It is very inconvenient. How can I inject everything into the .jar file?

Comment: You need to make sure you haven't used "Java Class Library" project.  You need to have created a "Java Application" project.  I don't know of any way to tell, other then one builds and deploys it's dependencies (application) and the other doesn't (deploy it's dependencies)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

See the NetBeans documentation on [Packaging and Distributing Java Desktop Applications](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/javase-deploy.html), especially the section on [Running and Distributing the JAR File](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/javase-deploy.html#run).

Comment: It didn't mention how to inject everything to .jar file at all :(